# Restore a Plugin's Default Settings

Tags: plugins, options

Is there a way to code "Restore Defaults" button into a plugin options page?

I'm writing a plugin right now that has sets up some default values on activation (via `register_activation_hook`), and I'd like to give users the option to restore those defaults again with a click.  Possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, answered my own question:

http://www.keyframesandcode.com/resources/javascript/jQuery/demos/populate-demo.html

Used that to update all the text and drop downs. Couldn't get it to work with my checkboxes, but a few other lines of jQuery took care of those.  I like the idea of just auto filling the form with the defaults, rather than submitting it right away.